# iOS 11 UINavigationBar UISearchBar and UIBarButtonItem overlap

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios11, uibarbuttonitem

In iOS 11, if you set a UISearchBar to be titleView of the navigationItem. Then add / remove UIBarButtonItem to navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems. The UIBarButtonItem will overlap with the UISearchBar.

[image]
Steps to reproduce:

1. New single view Xcode project
2. Embed ViewController in UINavigationController in storyboard
3. Modify ViewController.swift like this

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: nil, action: nil)
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let searchBar = UISearchBar()
           searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
           navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
       }

       override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
           super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
           if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
               navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
           } else {
               navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Environment: Xcode 9.2, iOS 11.2.2

My question is: is there a way for the UINavigationBar to layout items correctly or have I done something wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try DispatchQueue.main.async

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.button
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the overlapping happens again every time app was bring to the foreground from background. Also when using multi-tasking. I am trying to solve it by reconfigure bar buttons in a async block whenever needed.

Comment: I have to do the button configure again using `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `viewWillTransitionToSize` and when ever app enter foreground. What happens to Apple's QA?

Comment: I think it's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the `navigationItem.titleView` in `viewWillAppear`.

Set `titleView = nil` and back to search bar to force force Navigation Bar to layout again.

Something like:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.titleView = nil
    navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar
}
```

---

#### More details

I like the accepted solution using `traitCollectionDidChange`.

However, that solution does not work for me on (and only on!) iPhone 11 Pro Max (iOS 14.4 at the moment).

It is a very weird issue, but the reset in `viewWillAppear` is the only reliable solution I found working on all devices.